# Pytest asyncio - run multiple tests gives error regarding event loop

Tags: pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I am using pytest with pytest-asyncio to run async tests. What is strange is that these tests only work if there is exactly one of them. For example:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_foo():
    client = await get_db_connection()
    user = await client.DO_QUERY
    response = await FunctionUnderTest(
        db=client, ...args
    )
    assert response.id is not None


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_error_foo():
    client = await get_db_connection()

    with pytest.raises(MissingRequiredError):
        await FunctionUnderTest(
            db=client, ...args
        )
```

If I comment out either of those tests, the remaining one will pass, but running both together gives:

```
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<test_error_foo() running at /tests/test_function_under_test.py:44> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:184]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

I would have expected pytest-asyncio to create a single event loop and run all the tests sequentially, but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll hopefully get better mileage by using `pytest-asyncio-cooperative` which is designed around the use of a single event loop for all tests. `pytest-asyncio` on the other hand uses an event loop per test.

1. Install:

```
pip install pytest-asyncio-cooperative
```

2. Replace `pytest.mark.asyncio` with `pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative`

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative
async def test_foo():
    client = await get_db_connection()
    user = await client.DO_QUERY
    response = await FunctionUnderTest(
        db=client, ...args
    )
    assert response.id is not None


@pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative
async def test_error_foo():
    client = await get_db_connection()

    with pytest.raises(MissingRequiredError):
        await FunctionUnderTest(
            db=client, ...args
        )
```

3. Run the tests with `pytest-asyncio` OFF and sequential running of tests ON (ie. --max-asyncio-tasks 1):

```
pytest -p no:asyncio --max-asyncio-tasks 1 test_function_under_test.py
```

Admittedly, if you want to keep using `pytest-asyncio` you could rewrite your tests to use the event loop provided by `pytest-asyncio` and then explicitly use it in your test. I think you'd have to pass it into your code that is referencing the event loop.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of this `pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative`